# How do I make a password match custom validator show an error message on the password field in Angular 16?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a reactive registration form in Angular 16.

I have made a custom validation to check if the values in the form fields `password` and `confirm_password` match:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export const matchpassword : ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl):ValidationErrors|null => {

     let password = control.get('password');
     let confirm_password = control.get('confirm_password');
     if (password && confirm_password && password?.value != confirm_password?.value) {
        return { password_match : true }
     }
    return null; 
}
```

In `components\registration\registration.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { matchpassword } from "../../custom-validators/matchpassword.validator";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  public registrationForm!: FormGroup;
  public isSuccess: Boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  get form() { return this.registrationForm.controls }

  public registerUser() {

    if (this.registrationForm.status !== 'INVALID') {
      // Show success alert
      this.isSuccess = true;

      // Reset form
      this.registrationForm.reset();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), matchpassword]],
      confirm_password: ['', matchpassword],
      terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue],
    }, {
      validators: matchpassword
    });
  }
}
```

In `components\registration\registration.component.html` I have:

```html
<div *ngIf="isSuccess" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    Your signup was successful!
</div>

<form
    [formGroup]="registrationForm"
    (ngSubmit)="registerUser()"
    novalidate
  >
    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="firstName" class="form-label"> First name </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="firstName"
        formControlName="firstName"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['firstName']?.touched && form['firstName'].errors?.['required']"
        >The <i>First name</i> field is required</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['firstName'].touched && form['firstName'].errors?.['minlength']"
        >The <i>First name</i> must be at least 3 characters long</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="lastName" class="form-label"> Last name </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="lastName"
        formControlName="lastName"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['lastName'].touched && form['lastName'].errors?.['required']"
        >The <i>Last name</i> field is required</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['lastName'].touched && form['lastName'].errors?.['minlength']"
        >The <i>Last name</i> must be at least 3 characters long</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="email" class="form-label"> Email address </label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        formControlName="email"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['email'].touched && form['email'].errors?.['required']"
        >The <i>Email</i> field is required</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['email'].touched && form['email'].errors?.['email']"
        >Please provide a valid email address</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="password" class="form-label"> Password </label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="password"
        formControlName="password"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['required']"
        >The <i>Password</i> field is required</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['minlength']"
        >The password must have al least 6 characters</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['passwordcomplexity']"
        >The password is not complex enough</span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['password'].touched && registrationForm.errors?.['password_match']
        "
        >The passwords do not match</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="confirm_password" class="form-label">
        Confirm password
      </label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="confirm_password"
        formControlName="confirm_password"
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        formControlName="terms"
        id="terms"
        class="me-1"
      />
      <span class="text-terms text-muted"
        >I accept the
        <a href="#" class="text-success">Terms & conditions</a></span
      >
      <span
        class="invalid-feedback terms"
        *ngIf="form['terms'].dirty && form['terms'].errors?.['required']"
        >You must accept our Terms & conditions</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="pt-2">
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100"
        [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

#### The goal

If the passwords do not match, I want the error message "The passwords do not match" to show *on the password field*, as below:

[image: What I want]

#### The problem

Although the password is seen as invalid (the submit button is disabled), the error message does not show:

[image: What is happening]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you want to show the error ? inside the form input ? or in the next line ?

Comment: @brk  inside the form input

Comment: Have you ever debugged your code? In your validator, `control` contains the form **control** and not the form **group**. For that reason `control.get('password')` returns `null`. Your validator is just not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matchpassword` validator needs to be added to the form **group** rather than to some single control. Adding a validator to a control doesn't give you access to the other controls.

```js
this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: [
      '',
      [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), passwordcomplexity],
    ],
    confirm_password: ['', Validators.required],
    terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue],
  },
  {
    validators: [matchpassword],
  }
);
```

After fixing that, you need to adjust your error message to be displayed when the form group has an error rather than the form control:

```html
<span
  class="invalid-feedback"
  *ngIf="
    form['password'].touched &&
    registrationForm.errors?.['password_match']
  "
  >The passwords do not match</span
>
```

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wbynzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fregistration%2Fregistration.component.ts

Note: There are now some issues with overlapping error messages, which I didn't fix, as this is not related to the question

Comment: Yes, I have noticed the overlapping error messages. OI would love to know how to get read of them. :)

Comment: Quick fix would be to move the error message to the password repeat field. If it needs to stay on the password field, you will need to think about an order of precedence.

Comment: Why doesn't Angular "think" about an order of precedence? Why isn't that order the one in wich the messages appear in the component's template?

Comment: Based on what should Angular decide on an order? In the end those are business rules, and Angular doesn't care about business rules.

Comment: Why isn't that order the one in wich the messages appear in the component's template?

Comment: The form doesn't know about the error messages in the template. Changing this could have huge performance implications.

Comment: Please give an answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77481192/4512005)** too. Thanks!

Comment: really **NOT** the matchpassword validator **can** be added to the form group rather than to some single control., but it's not necesary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody will find the complete code that worked for me useful...

The custom validators `custom-validators\matchpassword.validator.ts`

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';
 
 export const matchpassword: ValidatorFn = (
   control: AbstractControl
 ): ValidationErrors | null => {
   let password = control.get('password');
   let confirm_password = control.get('confirm_password');
   if (
     password &&
     confirm_password &&
     password?.value != confirm_password?.value
   ) {
     return { password_match: true };
   }
   return null;
 };
```

and `custom-validators\passwordcomplexity.validator.ts`

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";
export const passwordcomplexity : ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl):ValidationErrors|null => {
    let password = control.value;

    let oneUppercase = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
    let oneLowercase = /[a-z]/.test(password);
    let oneDigit = /\d/.test(password);
    let oneSpecialCharacter = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/.test(password);
     
    if (!(oneUppercase && oneLowercase && oneDigit && oneSpecialCharacter)) {
      return { passwordcomplexity : true }
    }

    return null; 
}
```

In `app\components\registration\registration.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { matchpassword } from "../../custom-validators/matchpassword.validator";
import { passwordcomplexity } from '../../custom-validators/passwordcomplexity.validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  public registrationForm!: FormGroup;
  public isSuccess: Boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  get form() { return this.registrationForm.controls }

  public registerUser() {

    if (this.registrationForm.status !== 'INVALID') {
      // Show success alert
      this.isSuccess = true;

      // Reset form
      this.registrationForm.reset();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), passwordcomplexity]],
        confirm_password: [''],
        terms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue],
      },
      {
        validators: [matchpassword],
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In `src\app\components\registration\registration.component.html` I have:

```
<div *ngIf="isSuccess" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    Your signup was successful!
</div>

<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="firstName" class="form-label">
        First name
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      <span class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['firstName']?.touched && form['firstName'].errors?.['required']">The <i>First name</i> field is required</span>
        <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['firstName'].touched && form['firstName'].errors?.['minlength']">The <i>First name</i> must be at least 3 characters long</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="lastName" class="form-label">
        Last name
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="lastName" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['lastName'].touched && form['lastName'].errors?.['required']">The <i>Last name</i> field is required</span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['lastName'].touched && form['lastName'].errors?.['minlength']">The <i>Last name</i> must be at least 3 characters long</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">
        Email address
      </label>
      <input type="email" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['email'].touched && form['email'].errors?.['required']">The
        <i>Email</i> field is
        required</span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['email'].touched && form['email'].errors?.['email']">Please provide
        a valid email
        address</span>

    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="password" class="form-label">
        Password
      </label>
      <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['required']">The
        <i>Password</i> field is
        required</span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['minlength']">The
        password must have al least 6 characters</span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback"
        *ngIf="form['password'].touched && form['password'].errors?.['passwordcomplexity']">The password is not
        complex enough</span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form['password'].touched && registrationForm.errors?.['password_match']
        ">The passwords do not match</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <label for="confirm_password" class="form-label">
        Confirm password
      </label>
      <input type="password" id="confirm_password" formControlName="confirm_password"
        class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-element mb-2">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="terms" id="terms" class="me-1">
      <span class="text-terms text-muted">I accept the <a href="#" class="text-success">Terms &
          conditions</a></span>
      <span class="invalid-feedback terms" *ngIf="form['terms'].dirty && form['terms'].errors?.['required']">You
        must accept our Terms &
        conditions</span>
    </div>

    <div class="pt-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In order to *prevent validation messages overlap*, in the SCSS I do this to *display only the first message* in the DOM:

```
.invalid-feedback {
    display: none;

    &:first-of-type {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```